# How do I specify integers to be of a certain length via a JPA annotation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hbm2ddl

```
create table foo (id INT(10) not null ...)
```

Instead of declaring id as "INTEGER", I would like to specify a length restriction as mentioned above.

I use

@Entity
class Foo {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer id;
```

...
}

How should I specify the length restriction in my JPA model class, so that hbm2ddl automatically generates the schema as per my requirement.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that if you are using MySQL, specifying int(10) will not alter the actual storage capacity or range of integer data type (which is fixed). It simply specifies the display width of integer data types. The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column display width from being displayed correctly. [Numeric Types Ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "id",length=50, unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
 private Integer id;
```

In your case you are use annotaion/JPA. If you used mapping then use like this :

```
<property name="id" type="Integer" length="20"/>
```

try this one

Comment: Using length on a number type column does not work. From the javadocs on `@Column`:
`/**
     * (Optional) The column length. (Applies only if a
     * string-valued column is used.)
     */
    int length() default 255;`